# How to reload FullCalendar Contact when the value of a menu change using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin in my site to display calender event. What I am trying to add now is a drop down menu with name and if the drop down menu change value then Reload the events based on the value of the menu.

If another words, by default i load events owned by me. The drop down menu will have all users in one menu. From that menu I can change the user name to view other users events on the same page.

I have tried to add a .change() event on the drop down menu and refetchEvents on the fullCalendar but it is not working.

Can someone please help me with reloading this events by passing the value of the $('#users_menu').

The following is my current code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
          right: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },      

        events: {
            url: "ajax/getMyEvents.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                user_id: $('#users_menu').val()
            }
        },
        timeFormat: 'h:mm TT{ - h:mm} TT',
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',


        eventDrop: function(event, delta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {

            if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
            updateEvent(event, delta, minuteDelta, allDay, 'Drop', revertFunc); 
        },

        eventResize: function(event, delta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

            if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
            updateEvent(event, delta, minuteDelta, false, 'endResize', revertFunc); 
        }


    });


    $('#users_menu').change( function(){

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    });

});
```

Note that i pass my user_id value in my data method.

This code works on the load but when I change the user name in the drop down menu it does not reload the new events.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Could you jfiddle this?

Comment: I don't know how to do that since I am sending a AJAX request to the server. But I belive the issue is because $('#users_menu').val() is not beeing passed to the $('#calendar').fullCalendar in the refetch event

Comment: It's really strange, check the log of the ajax request!

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on the `.change()` function, this will allow you to see if `refetchEvents` is ever getting called.

Comment: @apfunk what do you mean by break point? I tried to add console.log( $(this).val() ); as the last line in the .change() event and that is writting to the console the user id as it should.  it feels that i need some how to pass the value to the fullCalendar.  because everytime I change the user it looks like it refresh the calender but with the same data. There is nothing wrong with the AJAX request as it is sending information back but for the same user over and over again.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

I had to `removeEventSource` then `√` then `refetchEvents` for this to work which is not cool :)

Here is my solution code for this

```
$('#users_menu').change(function() {

    var events = {
        url: "ajax/getMyEvents.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            user_id: $(this).val()
        }
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
}).change();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer.  It just helped me out.  I noticed through the .change(); makes the ajax call fire twice according to developer tools.

Comment: @steve Ajax call is fired twice, because addEventSource triggers it first time and refetchEvents does it again.

Comment: You saved my semester thank you despite I know that it's against stackoverflow's rules to post comments like mine!

Answer (score 4):

Try this.....  this function will fire event ajax again.....

```
$('#conrollerId').on('change', loadEvents);

function loadEvents() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bindCal(id) {
    var ddlStudio1Value = $("#ddlStudio1 option:selected").val();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetEvents", "FacultySchedule")',
            data: "{'status':'','StudioId':'" + ddlStudio1Value + "','FacultyId':0,'start':'" + start + "', 'end':'" + end + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];
                var EventIds = "0";
                $(doc).each(function () {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', $(this).attr('id'));
                    events.push({
                        id: $(this).attr('id'),
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start'),
                        end: $(this).attr('end'),
                        color: $(this).attr('color'),
                        textColor: $(this).attr('textColor'),
                        someKey: $(this).attr('someKey'),
                        allDay: $(this).attr('allDay'),
                        CreatedBy: $(this).attr('CreatedBy'),
                        StatusRemark: $(this).attr('StatusRemark'),
                        DurationMnt: $(this).attr('DurationMnt'),
                        Studio: $(this).attr('Studio')
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the solutions / answers worked for me.
However I found another similar question and a working answer in SOF.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
 $('#calendar').empty();
```

This works for me than any other.

Cited from: [FullCalendar: How to recreate/reinitialize FullCalendar or batch add multiple events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899995/fullcalendar-how-to-recreate-reinitialize-fullcalendar-or-batch-add-multiple-ev)

Answer (score 0):

In my calendar refetch event is not working, I removed the event and added new event like below.

Remove event

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', data.event.id);
```

You need to pass the event id to remove it.

Add Event

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', data.task);
```

I am passing task object to add the event, and from the back end how I am passing object

```
$task = [
          'id' => $task->id,
          'start' => $task->due_date,
          'end' => $task->due_date,
           'title' => $task->name,
           'color' => '#135846'
        ];
```

If you want to learn it step by step, I have full course on it where I perform create, show, edit, update and delete functionality into the calendar. You can visit the series with below link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rujgiTHLCqw&list=PLDc9bt_00KcL9j9VoMcccR4HMF3JtYndd&pp=iAQB