# FullCalendar: How to recreate/reinitialize FullCalendar or batch add multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am trying to batch add new events to the calendar but failed to find a convenient method to use. So I then decided to just reinitialize the view with new events array. So I tried the following:

```
var events = [
    {
        title: 'Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10),
        description: 'long description',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        title: 'background',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 11),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14),
        description: 'long description',
        id: 0,
        color: "#00FF00",
        textColor: "#000000",
        placeholder: true,
    }];
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: events
});
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

I can still see those events, meaning that the second initialization call does not actually work. Is there any work around in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [addEventSource()](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) like so:

```
.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events )
```

> Source may be an Array/URL/Function just as in the events option.
>   Events will be immediately fetched from this source and placed on the
>   calendar

Answer (score 5):

Just found a walkaround.. You could do

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: events
});
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

to destroy it and then recreate.

But still, I do not know how to batch-add events.

Comment: You saved my day!..Thanks :)

Comment: This is the best workaround I saw regarding this issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> var events = [];

Filled these events in my ajax call..

```
.map(JSON.parse(data),
    function(r) {
        events.push({
        id: r.id,
        title: r.title,
        desc: r.desc,
        allDay: true,
        start: moment(r.start).utc(),
        end: moment(r.end).utc()    }); });
```

then used it to render on the calendar..

```
var myCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar'); 
myCalendar.refresh = function() 
{    myCalendar.removeEvents();    
     myCalendar.addEventSource(events); 
};
    
myCalendar.refresh();
```

Comment: I was using .addEvent and added 1 by 1 all events in my calendar, it took 10 seconds. I tweaked my code to create an array[] and add the events using addEventSource and now it takes 1 second. From 10 seconds to 1 second. Thank you very much.