# fullcalendar, refetch events after insert data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar in codeigniter to display data, user will insert data by pressing button after that fullCalendar will display it. but my problem is, user have to refresh the page so data can be displayed in fullCalendar.

Below is my controller.

```
public function showRecords() {
    $employeeid = getSession('empid');
    $data = $this->attendance->getAttendanceRecords($employeeid);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And below is the script for initialize fullCalendar

```
$(document).ready(async function() {
        let recordJson;
        await $.post('<?= getURL('attendance/calendar') ?>', function(data) {
            recordJson = JSON.parse(data);
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            let calendarEl = document.getElementById('fullCalendar');
            let fullCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'attendanceLog',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'today,prev,next'
                },
                customButtons: {
                    attendanceLog: {
                        text: 'Attendance Log',
                        click: function(info) {
                            let recordObj = info.event
                            const recordURL = '<?= getURL('attendance/records/') ?>' + recordObj.id
                            if(recordObj) {
                                modalForm(
                                    'Attendance Records',
                                    'modal-sm',
                                    recordURL,
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                eventDisplay: 'background',
                events: recordJson,
                eventClick: function(info) {
                    let eventObj = info.event
                    const formURL = '<?= getURL('attendance/form/') ?>' + eventObj.id
                    if(eventObj) {
                        modalForm(
                            'Attendance',
                            'modal-md',
                            formURL,
                        )
                    }
                }
        });
            fullCalendar.render();
        }, 200);
    });
```

after user inserting data, i want fullCalendar will refetch latest data.
i'm already using fullCalendar.refetch() but it does'nt work so i make my own which is does'nt work too

```
function refetch() {
        const fullCalendar = document.getElementById('fullCalendar')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "<?= getURL('attendance/refetch') ?>",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            fullCalendar.render()
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            showError(thrownError + ", please contact administrator for further assistance");
        }
        });
    }
```

in network tab, function above is appearing but doesn't work the way i wanted.

code below is how data will be saved(might help you guys understand)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form-attendance').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let csrf = decrypter($("#csrf_token").val())
            $("#csrf_token_form").val(csrf);
            let link = "<?= getURL('attendance/clockin') ?>"
            let form_type = "<?= $form_type ?>"
            if(form_type == 'clocked') {
                link = "<?= getURL('attendance/clockout') ?>"
            }
            let data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: link,
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#csrf_token").val(encrypter(response.csrfToken))
                    $("#csrf_token_form").val("")
                    let pesan = response.pesan;
                    let notif = 'success';
                    if (response.sukses != 1) {
                        notif = 'error'
                    }
                    if (response.pesan != undefined) {
                        pesan = response.pesan
                    }
                    showNotif(notif, pesan)
                    if (response.sukses == 1) {
                        refetch();
                        close_modal('modaldetail')
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    showError(thrownError + ", please contact administrator for further assistance");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

please help me guys

Comment: I would try and switch out the event source, as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18729621/1427878 (Or perhaps rather make the event source AJAX to begin with, so that you don't have to change it halfway through.)

Comment: From fullcalendar's point of view you are just providing it with a static list of events in an array. Therefore refetch() doesn't work because it doesn't know where to fetch new events from. Implement your event feed as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed (or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function if you need more flexibility) - that way, fullCalendar will know the URL (or function) to request in order to retrieve new events from the source, and can run that whenever the date range is changed, or when you call refetchEvents

Comment: @ADyson I got error when I'm following that documentation, fullCalendar can't display the events even data are exist. [{"id":111,"title":"Attendance","start":"2024-03-12","clock_in":"16:05:01","clock_out":null,"allDay":true}]

Comment: That JSON  data looks valid, so for us to help you you with your problem, you will need to [edit] your question to show exactly what you've done, both in terms of the fullCalendar code changes and any server-side code you've written. Then we should have a [mre] of the issue from which we can more easily diagnose the problem. Thanks